# Why I get different values in scala comparing Long to Int

Tags: scala

```
def computeInt(string: String): Int ={
  if(string.isEmpty) 1
  else
    string.head.toInt*computeInt(string.drop(1))
}
def computeLong(string: String): Long={
  if(string.isEmpty) 1
  else
    string.head.toInt*computeLong(string.drop(1))
}
```

Problem:
computeInt("Hello") //I got correct "825152896"

computeLong("Hello") //I got wrong answer"9415087488"

This really puzzles me.

Comment: What is `computeAnotherWay`?

Comment: sorry my bad.there are two recursions

Comment: Could it be a overflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that `computeInt` returns the correct answer, when in fact `computeLong` is more accurate.
Let's take your case:

```
H: 72
e: 101
l: 108
l: 108
o: 111
```

in this case you should have:

`value = 72*101*108*108*101 = 9,415,087,488`

which is greater than `Int.MAX_VALUE` meaning that the result you see for `computeInt` is actually an overflow.